# create button with a transparent border that is only on the second part of the button

Tags: css

### Want to achieve

I have a header with 0.8 transparency and a button with a border of 0.8 in the same color.

The button need to be aligned so that the center is equal to the bottom of the header.

[image: good]

### Problem

When you place a 0.8 transparency border on a header that is the same color and also 0.8 transparency it is going to be darker.
[image: wrong]

### possible solution

https://jsfiddle.net/extranion/fnz1ccf0/2/

```css
* { 
    margin:0; padding:0; 
}
body { 
    background-image: url("http://gallery.photo.net/photo/8551440-md.jpg");
}
button { 
    background:none; border:none; 
}

header { 
    height:100px; 
    background-color: rgba(41, 52, 61, .8); 
}

.contact { 
    float:right; 
    height:100px; 
    width:200px; 
    position:relative; 
}

.wrap-btn { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:100%; 
    left:50px; 
    height:30px; 
    width:100px; 
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px; 
    background-color: rgba(41, 52, 61, .8); 
}
button { 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:10px; 
    left:10px; 
    width:80px; 
    height:40px; 
    background:orange; 
    border-radius:15px; 
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="contact">
            lorem ipsum
            <div class="wrap-btn">
                <button>inloggen</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

### Question

Is there a better solution where only the bottom part have a border?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if its a better solution, but its a different approach.
Working with after elements and gradients:

```
  button { 
  top: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
    margin-top:-28px;
  height:56px;
    border-radius:0px 0px 14px 14px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 49%,rgba(41, 52, 61, .8) 50%,rgba(41, 52, 61, .8) 100%); 
}

button:after{
    content:'login';
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    width:70px;
    height:15px;
    padding:10px 0px;
    background:orange;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dm8654ga/1/

Using gradients could be a good way, using after elements also - the only thing I don not like is that I used the content attribute for the text -> makes it difficult for translations etc.

PS: If the border would not be rounded, the whole thing would be lot easier (workin with boxshadows..)

Comment: I like that you are thinking about linear-gradient to solve the 50% height issue. What i don't like is that we need to put the content text in css. Thanks for you answer :) It's cool to see that different people create different solutions.